# Background-image in <div> doesn't display

Tags: html, css, background-image, yui-pure-css

The `background-image` within the `video id` (#video) isn't displaying. I've included the `pure grid`styles. I've tried alternate ways of using  tags, however later on i'd also like to add in a button in the middle of the image. Is there a way of using div tags to display my background-image? Thanks

The HTML code:

```
<div id="right_content">
              <div class="pure-g">
                  <div class="pure-u-10-24">
                      <h1 id="about">About</h1>
                      <p class="text chinese_paragraph"> 
                          (Some text)
                      </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pure-u-14-24 section2">
                      <div id="video">
                      </div>
                      <button>Watch</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#right_content {
    background-color: #414141;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.pure-g > div {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#about {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Yuanti SC",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p.text {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Yuanti SC",sans-serif;
}
.pure-g .section2 {
    padding-top: 42px;
}
#video {
    background-image: url("../images/video.png");
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#video` div has no size, it's width and height are 0px. Set a size to your div and it will solve the problem.

```
#video {
    background-image: url("../images/video.png");
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1a8jjmhf/)

Comment: I added a width and height to the background-image in the #video. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: Replace the url with the one in the example and see if it works. If it does, check your url

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to display the image in the video div. Try with a background-color first to see if it works, maybe wrong link to image. And check and make sure the video div has a width and height.